# AngularJS, display condition on $location and force refresh

Tags: angularjs, ng-show

I have been trying to hide DOM elements depending on routing conditions. So far so good using something like (in my MainCtrl):

```
 $scope.showMe = $location.path() ==='/';
```

and in HTML

```
 ng-if="!showMe
```

But it does not work without a manual refresh of the page, the condition seems not to be reevaluated by Angular. 
How can i force that?

Thanks for your help

Edit: 
The logic in my **app.js** file goes like 
`when('/home', {
        templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
      }).otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/home'
      });`

Comment: Did you try `ng-hide`?.

Comment: For some reason the same piece of code does not work with `ng-hide` or `ng-show`. It still works on user's refresh with `ng-if`. Any idea?

Comment: Do you have the code for take a look?

Comment: I added the routing code in my app.js file, i don't see what can i add more for you to look, everything is between the app.js for routing, the MainCtrl where i retrieve the true/false value for my ng-if, and the HTML where i put the ng-if condition.

Answer (score 0):

got it, passing through a function in my controller

```
$scope.whereami= function () {
  return $location.path();
}
```

and in html

```
ng-if="whereami() != myLocationCondition"
```

no need to refresh the page anymore :)
i wish i knew why tough ^^